# Access Token Data in IHttpActionResult request

Tags: web, asp.net-web-api2

I'm ussing MVC 5 and Web api 2. I send request from MVC with ajax or mvc controller to web api 2 IHttpActionResult action request. Also sending Bearer token . I need to read some parameters from the token for input parameters in mu query.I cant find any solution. Thanks

I try this in Web Api 2 IHttpActionResult action:

```
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders headers = this.Request.Headers; if (headers.Contains("user_id")) user = headers.GetValues("user_id").First();
```

In ajax call added this parameters to header. I think its working .

I now need  to send the same from the controller . I'm using MVC 5 Controller and 
 HttpClient to access my Web Api 2.

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) { client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);}
```

Comment: Ex.
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
// Here i need to access Token data to red some parameters from the token

}

Comment: it's not really clear what problem or question you have. Click on [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57587358/edit) below your post to add more details and maybe some code that shows what you're trying to do. What kind of token is it? JWT?

Comment: I try this System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders headers = this.Request.Headers;

            if (headers.Contains("user_id"))
               user = headers.GetValues("user_id").First();

Comment: i ajax call added this parameters to header

Comment: I now need how to send  the same from the controller . I'm using HttpClient. EX : using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);}

Comment: It's edited now